# MySQL 1253 COLLATION Error PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting this error when I am trying to create a MySQL table.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1253 COLLATION 'utf8_general_ci' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4'' in /home/vagrant/Projects/test_herbert/wp-content/plugins/TestHerbertPlugin/vendor/illuminate/database/Connectors/MySqlConnector.php on line 40( ! ) PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]:
```

This is the code that is breaking it. When I take it out the project works fine.

```
use Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager as Capsule;

Capsule::schema()->create('tasks-test', function($table) {
    $table->increments('id');
});
```

Thanks to anyone who manages to help me out.

Answer (score 0):

> This is the same answer I posted on [Getting an error when using COLLATE in a Mysql query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37062579/6294600)

Make sure that the collation you are using is compatible with your character set. (e.g. A collation of UTF8 is not compatible with UTF8MB4)

Use this statement to check your charset and collation (from [MySQL Database Character Sets and Collation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-database.html))

```
SELECT DEFAULT_CHARACTER_SET_NAME, DEFAULT_COLLATION_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA WHERE SCHEMA_NAME = 'db_name';
```

If they are different, you have to reconfigure your database.

Comment: How to reconfigure the database? Is there a SQL statement to change the character set of the DB?