# Getting an error when using COLLATE in a Mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to use the COLLATE clause in a MySQL query and I am getting an error. 
Here is my code:

```
<?php    

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE first_name LIKE '%" . $name ."%' COLLATE uf8_general_ci";

    $members = User::find_by_sql($sql);

?>
```

If I take out the COLLADE clause the query works properly.
Is it something wrong with the syntax?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the error message you are getting?

Comment: @Sean "Database Query Failed Last SQL Query: SELECT * FROM users WHERE first_name LIKE '%arturo%' COLLATE uf8_general_ci"

Comment: That looks like a generic php error message. Have you tried running the query directly in mysql to find out what the mysql error message is?

Comment: @Sean Oh ok, I did it and the mysql message is "ERROR 1273 (HY000) : Unkown Collation: 'uf8_general_ci' ". I tried with other different Collations and it is not recognizing none of them. What could it be?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE first_name LIKE '%" . $name ."%' COLLATE uf8_general_ci
```

What collation is UF8? Typographical errors can be easily overlooked.

It must be:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE first_name LIKE '%" . $name ."%' COLLATE utf8_general_ci
```

Also, make sure that the collation you are using is compatible with your character set. (e.g. A collation of UTF8 is not compatible with UTF8MB4)

Use this statement to check your charset and collation (from [MySQL Database Character Sets and Collation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-database.html))

```
SELECT DEFAULT_CHARACTER_SET_NAME, DEFAULT_COLLATION_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA WHERE SCHEMA_NAME = 'db_name';
```

Comment: Oh you are right about the typo. Now I am getting "COLLATION 'utf8_general_ci' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'cp850' My table collation is set to uft8_general_ci. Can you point me on where to change the character set as well which one is compatible with UTF8? Thanks.

Comment: Use this: ALTER TABLE 'TABLE' CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET UTF8 COLLATE UTF8_UNICODE_CI.

Comment: Did that, and still getting "COLLATION 'utf8_general_ci' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'cp850'. Also when asking for the information schemata with the statement in the answer you gently provided I got "Table 'table_name.information_schemata' doesnt exist"...